# How to decode G723.1 wav files?

Tags: ffmpeg

Telephone networks often use wav G723.1 encoded wav files, I can't find a codec anywhere that supports it and audacity/ffmpeg gets close but still doesn't sound right.

Comment: According to ffmpeg [General Documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/general.html#Audio-Codecs) G723.1 is supported for both encoding and decoding ...

Comment: ffmpeg would do "something" to it, but it still didn't sound correct. Turns out that you have to specify the input codec because it can't figure out what codec it is on it's own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/):

```
ffmpeg -i src.wav -acodec g723_1 -ac 1 -b:a 6300 output.wav
```